# How to decide if a design is very similar to my own work?

Tags: copyright, posters, copy-protection, competitions

**Edit:** They finally responded and the cartoonist and his work submitted has been disqualified from that competition.

I recently found out that a cartoon which was drawn just like one of my own posters has won a bronze in a contest in China. The cartoonist is from my country.

[image]

The left poster was designed by me **2-3 years ago** (2016-2017). The right cartoon won a bronze this year (2019). I uploaded my work on 3 social networks (Coroflot, Behance and Instagram) and pinned one of them into Pinterest as soon as I learned that doing so is useful (which was 2 years ago). Anyone can find my poster by searching **Water Poster** on Google and Pinterest. Isn't it something that we all should do?

Can we call the right cartoon a copy of my poster? Why? What's the right thing to do in these kind of situations?

Some says using different colors and designs, make the cartoon different. That doesn't sound like a logical reason to conclude it's not a copy. Everyone has his/her own style, even if he/she is using somebody else's idea. If that's the case, **can we just get exact ideas from somebody else and change its colors and some lines based on our styles, and call them ours?**

I've already read answers on [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31123/how-can-a-designer-decide-whether-a-competitors-design-is-similar-enough-to-thei). But designs on that page are too broad.

P.S. I'm not saying that the designer copied my work. I'm not sure what's right.

Comment: Hi mrmowji, I asked a similar question a while ago [What's the limit that defines a copy of a design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/113758/120647). Although it has been closed, it has a couple of answers that can help you. For me it's still a correct question to ask.

Comment: @Danielillo Thanks. There was some really good examples.

Comment: @Danielillo Based on your example of fingerprints, I added the times these designs are done. There is no record of that cartoon that's indexed before 2019 and I could find.

Comment: I voted to close this. I'm uncertain what answers you anticipate beyond "Yes" or "No" opinions. I do not see how any resolution to anything could be accomplished via any answer. If you feel the artwork is infringing upon your intellectual property, contact an attorney.

Comment: I'm also unsure if this question can be answered. The first example in the question @Danielillo links to is clearly plagiarism imo - both style and motif is copied. But in your case I don't think that it's impossible to imagine that someone else could get the same idea without having ever seen your work. If you could win a lawsuit against the other artist, imagine how easily you could just spew out simple drawings of different ideas and claim to be the owner. Imo your artwork must have same sort of importance for a brand or person and the "copy" must use your idea for something similar.

Comment: By the way, did you send your poster to the China contest jury?

Comment: It is really hard to get this plagiation case done. First the drop shape is common in hangmans nooses. Second your image does not really invoke water. So the only real commonality is that  you have  3 loops.

Comment: @Danielillo I did actually. No answer though.

Comment: @Wolff I know it's not impossible to come up with a same idea. Maybe you're right and I should forget about it :)

Comment: @joojaa If that's a common shape, so is the idea. And brings the question: Aren't we supposed to search for previous works on the same idea? I don't know how not-really-invoking-water matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My advice would be to let it be. The only thing the "copy" has in common with your work is the idea of a noose with a drop of water. The style is different and the context probably also.

It's not hard to imagine that someone could come up with this concept without knowing about your artwork.

Actually it seems that someone already created a poster with a noose and a drop of water back in 2008. Have a look at [this](http://cargocollective.com/cameronnelson/CSU-Water-Poster).

So your design isn't the original, but still I guess you feel that it's your original idea? It is! Doesn't matter that someone else *also* came up with it.

Comment: wow, we should bring Cameron Nelson to participate here :-)

Comment: This is a great find. Thanx for the research.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your effort. Well done. May I ask how did you find it?

Comment: Although I'm not sure the date on the link is correct (I'm not saying that's fake), and couldn't find other references to that poster, but I decided to accept your answer. It seems that letting it go is the best thing to do. I can't find what's really happened. No time and money to follow the case.

Comment: "The style is different and the context probably also". For future readers, I don't think  that being different in style matters and says nothing about how one comes up with an idea.

Comment: I did an [image search on DuckDuckGo for "noose water"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=noose+water&t=hi&iax=images&ia=images). Found it near the bottom.

Comment: (Please mind that I'm not a lawyer, so this is really just my personal opinion.) Maybe "style" isn't the correct word. I could have said "appearance". I do believe that it matters. If we remove all style/appearance from your work we are left with a sentence: "A noose where the hole is a drop of water.". That's the basic concept. If I posted that sentence before you made your image, I would have the copyright for that idea? That doesn't seem fair and I don't think the law works like that. It would kill all creativity.

Comment: @Wolff Thanks for the explanation. Yes, that's the basic concept. I can't say anything about that sentence (or idea) being copyrighted and I don't think that's what we're talking about (we're talking about implemented visible ideas). But you can think about how known algorithms (which are basically ideas) on Computer Science are copyrighted. You can't just code them with a programming language and call them yours.

Comment: @Wolff And I don't know how that'd kill all creativity, it's the opposite IMHO. It'll generate the maximum creativity if we're limited to create genuine works and not reimplementing others'. It might be good for practicing "to be" creative, but for actual projects, that doesn't seem to be creative.

Comment: I think you are contradicting yourself. You say "style doesn't matter". Then I say: "OK, let's remove style and reduce the idea to a sentence". Then you say: "a sentence about an idea can't be copyrighted, it needs to be implemented visually". Then we are back to the start: The idea itself can't be copyrighted, only the implementation. You can't implement an idea without giving it a style/appearance. You only own that specific implementation, not the sentence behind or any other specific implementations of the same idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95545/discussion-between-wolff-and-mrmowji).

Answer (score 1):

My lawyer told me that, in simple terms, a design infringes another if an uninformed person could mistake one for the other.

At the very least, one could be described as an alternate or alternative design to the other.

To me, the dead give-away is the conceptually identical filling-of-the-gap created in the empty loop created in the line shape. That's not a change from one shape or colour. That's a unique concept to my way of thinking.

I'd venture to say that another instance of a similar concept duplication is not available.

I'd vote for revocation of the award given to the latter "realistic rope" version.

Comment: See `:)` I'd kind of disagree. The *concept* can't be copyrighted and beyond the overall concept, next to nothing is similar - not the placement of the highlight, not the rope, certainly not the coloring or quality of execution..... In fact, the *only* aspects which are similar is the *idea* and the 3 rings on the noose..... and ideas aren't protected as intellectual property.... definitely an arguable case (for either side) in my opinion.

Comment: Not my down vote, BTW.

Comment: @Scott I see your point. I have an interesting dilemma, now, in that I agree with you, too.  It's the "turns" and where they are that "make" the rope. The realistic brown drawn "rope" version is just redundancy to push the issue which kills the elegance of the design. Good comment though. Thanx.

Comment: Thanks. Good to hear a lawyer's opinion. But as others have mentioned, beside that there was already another same work, we can't really conclude if the cartoonist has used my work or not, and that's a huge pressure if we keep thinking about. On the other hand, I don't believe that just using different colors or lines makes a work different. If he's a cartoonist, he draws the idea based on his own style. That says nothing about how he came up to the idea. That's not a logical reason to my mind.

Comment: @mrmowji **Ideals** are **not** protected intellectual property. Anyone is free to use any **idea**. It is the *only* the *implementation* of that idea which can be protected. Everyone reading this is free to go out and create their own "Noose with Water highlight" image. You can't claim ownership over a concept.

Comment: @Scott Honestly that doesn't make sense to me. I could say that for ideas that are not implemented yet and no one knows about them, but for those which are "out there", we can't easily say the same thing. An example from Computer Science world. You can't just get a known algorithm and try to implement it (using your programming language of choice) and claim the ownership of that algorithm.

Comment: @mrmowji An algorithm is the physical **implementation** of a non-tangible idea. it is *not* the idea itself. Ideas are not protected intellectual property. What you are suggesting is that since Google had an *idea* for a search algorithm, then no one else should be allowed to create a search algorithm.. .. Google having merely the **idea** should give them all rights to *any* similar concept??? I'll stress again that *ideas* or *concepts* **can not** be protected. There is *zero* intellectual property rights over an *idea*.

Comment: In fact, this is the *entire* reason things like Non Disclosure Agreements exist --- to prevent the sharing of *ideas* which otherwise can not be protected.

Comment: @Scott I think we have different understandings of what idea means. Idea is a thought or suggestion as to a possible course of action (based on dictionaries). Idea also means "aim or purpose". So, both "search engine" and "algorithms of a search engine" could be ideas. I don't think that google would be OK with sharing its base algorithms, and if it is, then it's publicly stated. If it's private then anybody can come up with that algorithm by her/himself and google can't argue.

Comment: @Scott Not being able to protect and idea has two meanings at least. First, the idea can't be protected, because that's not a logical thing to do. And second, the idea can't be protected, because we don't know how to do it. If by what you say, you mean the second case, then we're on the same path.

Comment: @mrmowji ideas are **not** tangible. Algorithms **are** tangible. The "**idea** if an algorithm" is **not** tangible.-- Sorry I simply can not fathom what the struggle is here.

Comment: @Scott Actually it's the implementation of an algorithm which is tangible. Even if we see from your point of view, if algorithms are implementations of ideas, so are designs. We can protect algorithms, yet we can't do the same thing for designs. If you just put the steps of an algorithm into words differently, it doesn't make the algorithm yours. Please note that I still believe algorithms are ideas.

Comment: You are posting in circles. You are now repeating *exactly* what I wrote previously and you were arguing about. Algorithms are **not** ideas. Algorithms are **TANGIBLE** mathematical calculations and language implementations. I'm sorry you aren't understanding this. I can't help explain logic any further.

Comment: @Scott How I was posting in circles? My previous comment was just an assumption (if we were seeing from your point of view), not my real point of view. And what do you mean by language implementations? Sorry if I didn't/don't get what you mean.

Comment: @Stan would you please simplify or explain this line for me :) * give-away is the conceptually identical filling-of-the-gap created in the empty loop*

Comment: The cartoon version of the pun would fail using any fill that was not blue (universal liquid) or red (the pulp-fiction version liquid). The metaphor is a liquid where there cannot be. Notice the thin black stress marks in the "drop" container that is supposed to be a void. The details give-away the literal interpretation of the pun by the cartoonist that is more elegantly implied in the minimalist version. Try any other single colour for both the b/g and the gap without the use of the 'ping' in the gap. I think I may have made the line explanation worse. @Vikas Thank you for asking, though.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be more clues to the context of both pieces to determine that. I can figure yours but not so much the other's.

Yes they look the same, but without the context, both are a hanging rope with a drop.

In all honesty, I don't believe any other human being would've got there without much help due to the simplicity and universality of both simbols.

Comment: As I replied to a comment, if that's a common shape and those symbols are simple and universal, so is the idea. And brings the question: Aren't we supposed to search for previous works on the same idea? How about judges?

Comment: Absolutely agree. We need to stay current in our disciplines to not repeat ideas if we wanna bring some differentiating value to our work. And so for the judges. And so for ourselves.